# Fit table to specific width

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I created tables with this behavior:

- On screen width 1302px or larger, the table width are fixed to 1302px. That means the table that initially smaller than 1302px are expanded (I already fixed this on second table) and the big table are shrinked (the overflow content text may be shown vertically / more than one line, this is my question on first table)
- On screen width smaller than 1302px, the table layout rule are still the same as in larger screen, but the viewport is 100% minus margin of the screen.

This is what I did so far (the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcdq9ft0/3/) so you can see it better):

```js
var checked = 0;
var rowCount = $("td.checkbox-action").length;
$("#table1 tr:odd, #table2 tr:odd").addClass("alternate-bg");


var currentWidth = 0;
var shrink;
var expand;

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() != currentWidth) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1366) {
      $("table").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find ("tr").width() >= 1302) {
          if ($(this).attr("data-shrinked") == 0) {
            clearTimeout(shrink);
            shrink = setTimeout(shrinkTable($(this)), 100);
            $(this).attr("data-shrinked", 1);
          }
        }
        else {
          if ($(this).attr("data-expanded") == 0) {
            clearTimeout(expand);
            expand = setTimeout(expandTable($(this)), 100);
            $(this).attr("data-expanded", 1);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      $(".table-generic").css({"width": "100%"});
      $(".table-generic").css({"min-width": "0"});
      $(".table-generic").find("tbody").css({"width": "100%"});
      
    }
    currentWidth = $(window).width();
  }
});

function shrinkTable(obj) {
  if (obj.attr("data-expanded") == 0) {
    obj.find("tr").each(function() {
      $(this).find("td").not(":first").css({"padding-left": "12px"});
      $(this).find("td").not(":last").css({"padding-right": "12px"});
      $(this).find("th").not(":first").css({"padding-left": "12px"});
      $(this).find("th").not(":last").css({"padding-right": "12px"});
    });
    obj.css({"width": "1302px"});
    obj.css({"min-width": "1302px"});
    obj.find("tbody").css({"width": "100%"});
    obj.find("td").css({"text-overflow": "display"});
    console.log("shrink");
  }
}
    
function expandTable(obj) {
  if (obj.attr("data-shrinked") == 0) {
    var remainingWidth = 1302 - obj.find("tr").width();
    var colNum = obj.find("th").length;
    var extraPadding = (remainingWidth / ((colNum - 1)*2)) + 12;
    console.log(remainingWidth);
    obj.find("tr").each(function() {
      $(this).find("td").not(":first").css({"padding-left": extraPadding + "px"});
      $(this).find("td").not(":last").css({"padding-right": extraPadding + "px"});
      $(this).find("th").not(":first").css({"padding-left": extraPadding + "px"});
      $(this).find("th").not(":last").css({"padding-right": extraPadding + "px"});
    });
    obj.css({"min-width": "1302px"});
    obj.css({"margin-left": "50%"});
    obj.css({"transform": "translateX(-50%)"});
    obj.css({"min-width": "1302px"});
    obj.find("tbody").css({"width": "1302px"});
    console.log("expand");
  }
}
```

```css
.dashed-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 48px; 
}

table.table-generic {
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 1302px;
}

.table-generic tr {
  
}

.table-generic tr.first-row {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #D1D1D1;
  cursor: default;
}

.table-generic tr.first-row:hover {
  background: #fff; 
}

.table-generic td, th {
  text-align: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.table-generic tr.selectable-row:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-generic th {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.alternate-bg {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.selected-bg,
.selected-bg:hover {
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  outline: solid 1px #fff !important;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-generic td.icon {
  text-align: center; 
  padding-left: 0;
}

i {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.table-sort i {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.money {
  text-align: right !important; 
}

.history a {
  color: #0099ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button {
  height: 32px;
  width: 48px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

button i {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00c983;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FF7979;
}

.table-action {
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-action input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.4s;
}

.checkbox-checked {
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition: border 0.4s;
}

.checkbox-input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox i {
  color: #00c983;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.table-generic th:first-child,
.table-generic td:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px;
}

#table1 th:first-child,
#table1 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.table-generic td:last-child {
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.table-action-last {
  padding-right: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

th.table-action-last {
  cursor: default;
}

.table-sort {
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.table-pagination {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.table-pagination-btn i {
  color: #333; 
}

.table-pagination-btn {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  height: 38px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each {
  line-height: 38px; 
  width: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each:first-child {
  border-left: transparent; 
}

.table-pagination-btn-each:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each i {
  font-size: 8px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.table-pagination-btn-each.selected-page {
  background-color: #00c983;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.pagination-disabled,
.pagination-disabled:hover {
  cursor: default;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.pagination-disabled i {
  cursor: default;
  color: #aaa;
}

.table-generic td .yes-no {
  color: #333; 
  cursor: default;
}

.table-generic td .fa-minus {
  font-size: 8px; 
}

.yes-no-cell {
  text-align: center !important;
  padding-right: 32px !important;
  color: transparent;
}

.table-generic td .input-text {
  height: 30px; 
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 118px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-amount {
  text-align: right; 
  padding-right: 28px !important;
}

.input-amount-row {
  position: relative;
}

.spinner-table {
  top: 8px !important;
  right: 12px !important;
}

.table-view-link {
  color: #0099ff; 
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.table-view-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  color: #777;
}

.spinner-up i:hover,
.spinner-down i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.spinner-down i {
  transform: translateY(-1px); 
}

a:hover {
  color: #006BB3;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.table-caption {
  margin-top: 24px; 
}

td .fa-check {
  margin-left: 1.5px; 
}

#table2 td {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dashed-wrapper">

<table class="table-generic" id="table1" data-shrinked="0" data-expanded="0">
  <tr class="first-row">
    <th class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></th>
    <th class="table-action table-action-last">Edit</th>
    <th class="table-sort" id="req-no">Request No.<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-id">Employee ID<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-name">Employee Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>  
    <th class="table-sort" id="fam-member">For Family<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="req-date">Request Date<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th>Editable Example</th> 
    <th>Total Amount</th> 
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Approval History</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRAVEL/04/005</td> 
    <td>EMP004</td>
    <td>I Putu Yudi Haryasa</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>04 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">300,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MEDICAL/04/004</td>
    <td>EMP005</td>
    <td>Daniel Giovanni Gunawan</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>04 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">550,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MEDICAL/04/003</td> 
    <td>EMP006</td>
    <td>Muhammad Nadzeri Munawar</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>03 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">4,500,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MEDICAL/03/002</td> 
    <td>EMP007</td>
    <td>Glenn Kristanto</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>02 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">3,000,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRAVEL/03/001</td> 
    <td>EMP008</td>
    <td>Hendryanto Fudiko</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>02 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">150,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRAVEL/02/001</td> 
    <td>EMP004</td>
    <td>I Putu Yudi Haryasa</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>28 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">300,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MEDICAL/01/005</td>
    <td>EMP021</td>
    <td>Daniel Widjaja</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>25 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">550,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MEDICAL/01/004</td> 
    <td>EMP020</td>
    <td>Faris Kurniawan</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>25 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">4,500,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/ENTERTAINMENT/01/002</td> 
    <td>EMP015</td>
    <td>Romy Kusuma</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>11 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">3,000,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/ENTERTAINMENT/01/001</td> 
    <td>EMP006</td>
    <td>Muhammad Nadzeri Munawar</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>09 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">150,000.00</td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--<div class="table-pagination">
  <ul class="table-pagination-btn">
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each pagination-disabled"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each pagination-disabled"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each selected-page">1</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each">2</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each">3</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>-->
  
<div class="caption table-caption">Multi-select rows without link</div>
  
<table class="table-generic" id="table2" data-shrinked="0" data-expanded="0">
  <tr class="first-row">
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-id2">Employee ID<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-name2">Employee Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>  
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-type">Employment Type<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="start-date">Start Date<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="organization">Organization<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="job-title">Job Title<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th>Action Example</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP001</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Eric Jessen</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Software Development Engineer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP002</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Andi</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Software Development Engineer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP003</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Felix Adhinata</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jul 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Software Development Engineer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP004</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Ricky Yudianto</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jul 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Software Development Engineer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP005</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Stefanie Suanita</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Project Manager</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP006</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Dinna Amelina</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Project Manager</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP007</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Stella Kurniawan</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jul 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Project Manager</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP008</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Monika Sembiring</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jul 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>Project Manager</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP009</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Melina Mayella Sujono</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>UX Designer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td>EMP010</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="table-view-link">Fransiska Handayani</a></td>
    <td>Permanent</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2016</td>
    <td>ICT</td>
    <td>UX Designer</td>
    <td><a class="button green-btn table-btn">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--<div class="table-pagination">
  <ul class="table-pagination-btn">
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each pagination-disabled"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each pagination-disabled"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each selected-page">1</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each">2</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each">3</li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
    <li class="table-pagination-btn-each"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>-->
  
<div class="caption table-caption">Non-selectable rows with link</div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My question is, how to shrink a large table to exactly 1302px? Vertical text overflow is okay as long as the row height follows the text height. And also, can I make it so on the screen larger than 1302px my tables are center aligned to the screen?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the table with a div.
The div would be witdth 1302px, The table would be 100% width

Answer (score 1):

To center the table:

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:1302px">
 <table style="width:100%"></table></div>
</div>
```

This way your table will always be 1302px and always centered.